# java @action method parameters in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have @Action for example:

```
@Action
public void example(String name){
//sth to do
}
```

and I would like to add this method to button generated in netbeans. When I click to Customize Code and write:

```
myButton.setAction(example(myButton.getName()));
```

I'm getting error:
'void' type not allowed here.

Why I can't do like this? :/ @Actions generated by netbeans are also return void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myButton.setAction` is a function which expects an argument. `example` is a function which does not return anything.

`myButton.setAction(example(...))` passes the value returned by an invocation of `example(...)` to `setAction`.

Do you see why that's a problem?

Comment: I think I do. Action method needs Action but it gets void! :) Thank you!